# Host configured with both resolvconf and dnsmasq, restarting dnsmasq keeps pointing to old servers

Tags: dnsmasq, resolv.conf, host-name-resolution, resolvconf

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS host. It is configured to use `dnsmasq` for DNS forwarding, rather than use `resolv.conf` populated with nameservers. The configuration is standard wherein `resolv.conf` just has:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search redacted.searchfield.com
```

The host's configured `/etc/resolv.dnsmasq` has 4 nameservers configured. When I restart the dnsmasq service, it points to 3 nameservers that were configured on the host at one time (but no longer), and writes them automatically to `/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf`, ignoring the 4 defined nameservers in `/etc/resolv.dnsmasq`.

I can get the service to properly read the correct nameservers if I enter the four of them in `/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf` and leave the `dnsmasq` service running. However, if I restart the service it just points to these 3 old nameservers again.

Is this cached somewhere? I'm not using `nscd` here. I'm wondering if maybe the `resolvconf` service is causing an issue, and should not be run alongside `dnsmasq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to stop `resolvconf` and have noticed that after restarting `dnsmasq` the correct nameservers are written/consumed in `/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf`.